# Can I run a JavaFX application via Web Start with Java 6?

Tags: java, javafx, java-web-start, java-6

I want to offer a JavaFX-Application online via WebStart.
Is it possible to launch the application if the user only has JDK 1.6?

If it isn't possible "out of the box", can I somehow include the neccessary jars in the application?

Comment: You need to manually include The fxrt.jar file as a dependency (not 100% sure if latest versions are 1.6 compatible though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I am pretty sure that Java FX was usable in *later* versions of 1.6.
2. It is neither legal nor practical to supply the JRE (or separately Java FX) in Jars.
3. The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).